# Two instance of two ec2 different AWS accounts to share same security group

Tags: amazon-ec2

Can you have two ec2 instances of two different AWS account in same region to share same security group?

Comment: Since security groups are user specific, no. But you can give access to each group

Comment: do you mean, I can give have two groups in each account and then give access to each? is the security group id unique per account or per region?

Comment: It works per region. You can provide access to another security group. It doesn't have to be the same account either.